# Submitting answers in Python on Codechef, every submission shows the same error

Tags: python, eof

I am submitting the answers in Python on Codechef but each and every submission shows the same error to me. What's wrong in the code format?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "prog.py", line 1, in <module>
     EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Code:

```
t = int(input())

for i in range(t):
    n = input()
    num = n
    result=0
    while (num>0):
        num = num%10
        result += num
    k=10 - result

    print (10*result + k)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not converting your input which comes as string to int

```
n = int(input())
```

you are double defining `num` and `n` which are in your case the same. so `num` comes as string too and this may throw an eof-error.

Comment: I've changed the code according to what you said. EOF is gone.
It now shows the error  - SIGTSTP 
Any idea how do I tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run code which takes `input` in IDE mode then you must provide `Custom Input` (in the box below the IDE, using the checkbox next to `Run`), otherwise you will get this error (also labelled 'Runtime error' - 'NZEC' in case anyone finds this from Google).

`Run` and `Submit` are both different functions. In the case of `Submit`, Codechef provides its own test cases. But in the case of `Run`, you must provide the input yourself.

Try checking the `Custom Input` box and typing a `2` or something similar in there before you click `Run`.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank You. Now that I put in custom input given in the example, I get this error - SIGTSTP
Any clue how do I tackle this?

Comment: That's because your inner loop `while (num>0):` never terminates (`num` is always greater than 0 for most inputs), causing the maximum execution time to be exceeded. If your second and subsequent inputs are multiples of ten, the run finishes successfully.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't even look there. Damn!